# Get value of HTML element without ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a sample of how it looks like:

```
"<span class="value">7,611</span>"
```

I need to get it's value (7,661, no need to convert it to number) in C#.

Comment: have you tried the html agility pack?

Comment: Where is this HTML element coming from?

Comment: This seems to be a javascript question, where's the C# come in?

Comment: Is that the *only* html you're dealing with?  If so, this could be solved with a trivial split on both the open and closing equality signs.

Comment: @Daniel: No, I heard of it but never used it (I'm a newbie)

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: I need to implement it in c# code.

Comment: @George: Length of value is not always the same...

Comment: Try my solution posted below. 
Just make sure to add 
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: You really shouldn't handle HTML elements in the C# code, This why we have JavaScript...

Comment: @gdoron - What makes you say that? The DOM is not limited to JavaScript. You really should look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) as an example.

Comment: @Oded. That's still awkward in normal scenario. extract values from HTML elements Server-Side... Weird!

Comment: @gdoron - Normal scenario? Normal for who? You are making assumptions.

Comment: No reason to get complicated here. If he isn't actually using the HTML as HTML, then just treat it as XML and use the built in .NET XML library for the solution. No reason to get overly technical.

Comment: @Corylulu - Problem with that is that there is lots of HTML out there that is not valid XML and would throw when trying to load into `XmlDocument`. The HTML Agility Pack doesn't have that issue.

Comment: The question isn't really specific enough for anyone to provide a best solution scenario.  Are you parsing files? Xml nodes? Scraping web pages? Each of these would have a different solution that would make the best sense for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a C# solution, try treating it as XML

```
 var reader = new XmlDocument();
 reader.LoadXml("<span class=\"value\">7,611</span>");
 var node = reader.SelectSingleNode("/span");
 string s = node.InnerText;
```

Edit: Tested, this works.

Comment: This will fail if the HTML is not well formed XML.

Comment: It all depends on what he is bringing in. If this is some random sites HTML, then there could be problems, but if he is managing both sides, then there is no problem.